# SQL Server | IsNull | DateTime and SmallDateTime

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have the following table :

```
create table #temp_1234
(
    field1 varchar(50) null,
    field2 datetime null,
    field3 smalldatetime null
)
```

and, say, I insert the following row into it :

```
insert into #temp_1234
(field1, field2, field3)
values ('Val1','2016-09-16 23:59:59.000',NULL)
```

---

If I execute the query

```
select field2 from #temp_1234
```

the result I get is '***2016-09-16 23:59:59.000***'.

---

But when I execute the query

```
select ISNULL(field3,field2)  from #temp_1234
```

the result turns up to be '***2016-09-17 00:00:00***'.

---

How is it that even though in both the queries the same column is being returned, the result is different in the two cases ?

I understand that '**smalldatetime**' is precise upto a minute, and '**datetime**' is precise upto a second. But how does introducing a null check change the precision of the result returned ?

Comment: isnull forces the datatype of the first input (or rather, converts the second to the first). e.g. `DECLARE @var1 VARCHAR(5); DECLARE @var2 VARCHAR(10) = 'asdfghjkl;'; SELECT ISNULL(@var1, @var2);` will produce 'asdfg'... so you're forcing field2 to become a smalldatetime in the isnull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) utilizes two params, the `check_expression` and the `replacement_value`.  As stated in the docs for `replacement_value`:

*Is the expression to be returned if check_expression is NULL. replacement_value must be of a type that is implicitly convertible to the type of check_expresssion.*

In essence, the SQL Query engine is implicitly converting the values for comparison.  `Datetime` has an accuracy of [3.33ms](http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp), so that most likely accounts for the rounding.

If you want to get more control over the conversion, consider using [explicit conversions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx) such as `CAST` or `CONVERT`.

This might also be a good use case for the [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function, rather than `ISNULL`.

Answer (score 0):

isnull casts the second value to the first value format.

this is even clearer:

declare @date date, @datetime datetime = getdate()
select isnull(@date, @datetime)

Answer (score 0):

```
select ISNULL(field3,field2)  from #temp_1234
```

When you exceute the above query, value of "field2" is converted to type `smalldatetime` because data type of field3 is `smalldatetime`. That's why ISNULL is returning a different value. To verify you can run the below query:

```
select cast(field2 as smalldatetime) from #temp_1234
```

In `smalldatetime` the seconds section is always zero(00). if `datetime` value has seconds greater than or equal to 30 than 1 minute is added to resulting `smalldatetime` value and seconds are set to zero. For seconds less than 30 resulting `smalldatetime` value has seconds part set to 00 and minute section same as before.

In your case `datetime` value is :'2016-09-16 23:59:59.000'. Since seconds section of datetime value is greater than 30, so 1 minute is added to the resulting `smalldatetime` value which gives the value : '2016-09-17 00:00:00'.